# Cant run Shell script in Oozie using Hue

Tags: oozie, hue

I am trying to run shell script in Oozie using Hue. However it is not running and give exception.

My Shell script file:

```
#! /bin/bash
hive -e 'desc emptable;'
```

=======================================

Also added same script file in FILE option in script action.

=======================================

Gives exceptions:
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

=========================================

I also tried with hive-site file, added in FILE option. but not worked.

Comment: What happens when you execute your script from the command-line ? Does it have correct execution permission ?

Comment: Yes, Script was ran without any exceptions. and give correct result

Answer (score 0):

Oozie has a **specific Hive action**, and for a good reason: on a standard Hadoop setup, Hive/Pig/whatever are *not* installed on the "slave" nodes.

I suggest that you read some documentation on your own.

Comment: I have some dynamic queries, that is why I am using shell scripting to run Hive queries. Ex. Most of the queries have dynamically populate columns and where is also dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logs of the action on the graph of the workflow dashboard page, it should print what really happened.

In the latest Hue, there is even an [HiveServer2 action](http://gethue.com/new-apache-oozie-workflow-coordinator-bundle-editors/).

Comment: Yes I used HiveServer2 action.

Comment: So your script should only be 'desc emptable'

Comment: yes and I also added hive.site.xml as a file option and got the exception Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out (state=42000,code=40000)